# google app engine datastore get fails if I create the key using ancestor relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python, ancestor

When I insert a message into datastore I create a key using the sequence number of the message and create an ancestor relationship with the user who sent the message.  When I try to retrieve the message using a key created from just the sequence number, it fails.  If I change the insertion to use a key that is based on just the sequence number, the later retrieval succeeds.

Code-wise

**This fails:**

Storage:

```
p_key = ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,sendingUser)
c_key = ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,prof['seqNum'],parent=p_key)
prof['key']=c_key
StoredBcastMsg(**prof).put()
```

Retrieval fails

```
msgToRet=ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,seqNum).get() #Fails even though sequence number is there in the store
```

**This succeeds:**

Storage:

```
prof['key']=c_key
StoredBcastMsg(**prof).put()
c_key = ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,prof['seqNum'])
```

Retrieval succeeds:

```
msgToRet=ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,seqNum).get() #Succeeds
```

Is this expected behavior?  I thought the only difference in adding a parent= tag while creating the key is to create an ancestor relationship that allows efficiently answering queries like "give me all messages sent by user X."

Comment: Nope your assessment of the purpose of an ancestor is mistaken. See the answer below.  It is really about entity groups. You can use a normal query  if all your after is parent/child relationships and don't need or want entity groups.  Also the ancestor of an entity group can not be changed.  You can have to delete and create with a different key if you wish to change the parent in an entity group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent key is part of the child key and you need the full key to retrieve the entity.

So, to retrieve a child entity, you need to know the full key, meaning you need to know the parent key.

Note: the parent-child relationship via keys does not create a relational relationship in the sense that normal SQL databases have it. It merely puts the parent and child in the same "entity group" (fancy word for putting entities on the same server), which allows you to do transactions on them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So, it looks like I need to query by kind filtered by property to get what I want (get all the messages sent by user X) if I use sequence number as the key.

Answer (score 0):

As you said above:

```
p_key = ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,sendingUser)
c_key = ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,prof['seqNum'],parent=p_key)
prof['key']=c_key
StoredBcastMsg(**prof).put()
```

this succeeds.  To retrieve this entity, you must use the exact same key:

```
msgToRet=c_key.get()
```

Or, in a longer format:

```
p_key = ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,sendingUser)
msgToRet=ndb.Key(StoredBcastMsg,seqNum,parent=p_key).get()
```